# unrecognized selector sent to class. 'calling methods in ClientViewController.mm'

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

I am trying to call a method in my **ClientViewController.mm** class and keep getting this error:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+ [ClientViewController TestMethod]: 
 unrecognized selector sent to class
```

I have another class that implements an interface.

```
void AppleRecognitionStatusObserver::onRecognitionStatusChanged
                                       (RecognitionStatus newStatus) {
    switch(newStatus) {
        case kInProgress:
            [ClientViewController TestMethod];
            break;
        ....etc
    }
}
```

How can I call the **ClientViewController** methods from another C++ class?

client view controller.h

```
//imports UIKit etc
@interface ClientViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioRecorderDelegate>{
    IBOutlet UIButton *recoButton;
    // some other buttons
}
@end

// and the .mm
//#imports....
@interface ClientViewController ()
@end
@implementation ClientViewController
-(void)TestMethod{
    outLabel.text = @"Has been called!";
}
```

Comment: Does `ClientViewController` have a class method called `TestMethod`?

Comment: Well the ClientViewController I'm referring to are the default ClientViewController.h/mm that are created for you when you create a new iOS app. The clientViewController inherits from UIViewController. In my clientViewController.m file there is a method named TestMethod. I will edit to show

Comment: But is it a class method?

Comment: Re: your edit - there's your problem.  You're trying to invoke an instance method as a class method. You can't do that.  Call `TestMethod` on an *instance* of `ClientViewController`, not on the class itself.

Comment: you should also start your method names with a lower case character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure that your ClientViewController.m has a method implementation for testMethod
Like so:

```
+(void)TestMethod {
    // some code here
}
```

Your ClientViewController.h should have a matching header declaration like so:

```
+(void)TestMethod;
```

If you need an instance method, instead of a class method make sure to change the + to a - like so:

```
-(void)TestMethod {
    // some code here
}
```

and

```
-(void)TestMethod;
```

Comment: changing to a class method worked great. thanks! now how to I access and instance variable from class method? <pre><code>+(void)TestMethod{ label.text = @"some Text";} </pre></code>

Comment: @MatthewKnudsen: Have a look at [Programming with Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html) and [Learning Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/) on developer.apple.com

Comment: @MatthewKnudsen, you can't access instance variables from a class method.  If you had multiple instances, how would you pick which instance to affect?